# Correct word order and subject-verb agreement: "..his associate volunteers..."

Tags: grammar, subject-verb-agreement

Please consider the sentence below:

> Mr. Moretti has to go to Washington on a business trip unless his associate volunteers to go.

This is a quote from the book: English Grammar Digest, by Trudy Aronson, page 28.

Is this sentence incorrect?

I think the author has meant:

> Mr. Moretti has to go to Washington on a business trip unless his associate volunteers [have] to go.

**Edit**: I think that way because books are at the highest level of confidance for reading and it very rarely happens to see a grammar mistake in a grammar book. Besides, it's the only remedy in my mind (for the time being) to be able to consider the sentence correct.

Do you agree please?

Comment: This is not "incorrect". _Volunteer_ is a **verb** here, not a noun. Use your English dictionary to learn what it means.

Comment: @P.E.Dant: So what does the "**unless his associate volunteers to go.**" mean please?

Comment: You can learn it without our help, if you simply consult your English dictionary to learn the meaning of the verb _to volunteer_. You will learn, in that dictionary, that _volunteer_ often takes an _infinitive_ (such as _"to go_".)

Comment: I'm curious, is it just the word "volunteers" that is confusing? Or is it the entire phrase?

Comment: Note: in this clause, the noun phrase _his associate_ is the subject of the verb _volunteers_.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The original sentence is fine.

Let's treat it as two phrases, joined together by the conjunction "unless":

> Mr. Moretti has to go to Washington on a business trip.
>
> His associate volunteers to go.

The first sentence is good, and you recognize that. As for the second? You have a subject ("his associate"), a verb in the third-person present tense ("volunteers"), and the verb "to go", which stays in the infinitive because it's preceded by a verb that has already been conjugated. This sentence is good as well.

Comment: ___Volunteer___ is one of a limited set of words in English that may be either a verb or a noun; the verb form and the noun form are related, in that _a volunteer_ (noun) is a person who _volunteers_ (verb). The O.P. appears to have confused the two usages, and interpreted _volunteers_ as a noun, modified by the adjective _associate_, rather than interpreting _volunteers_ as a verb, indicating what the noun (_associate_) did.

Comment: Thanks. I don't know how I confused such a trivial thing!

Comment: @JeffZeitlin That is a very good point I forgot to consider. Thanks for covering it.

Comment: (For what it's worth, _associate_ is also in that set of words!)

Comment: @Abbasi Everyone makes mistakes! I think your command of English is quite good, and the fact that you questioned this sentence shows that you are thinking and paying attention. Remember: the dictionary is your friend!

Comment: @JeffZeitlin It's a set, but hardly "limited"! Just in the b's, I can start with _back, bail, balance, balloon, ban, bandage, bank, bare, bargain, battle, beam, bear, beat, bend..._ I'm sure there are thousands.

Comment: @JeffZeitlin: Well, although I gave a +1 to your comment, I ought to go along with P.E.Dant's point of view on that set! To me too, such a set has numerous items in itself having both forms of verbs and nouns. :)