# Use of S and es

Tags: subject-verb-agreement, present-tense

> Finally, results of the proposed technique and existing 
>   technique are compared which **show** that our proposed technique **acts** significantly to achieve better 
>   results in terms of cost, wait, and time of the appliances.

the words in bold are followed s or not. Kindly guide me.

Comment: Welcome to ELL.SE. One of the goals of Stack Exchange is to build a library of definitive answers that will be of help to future visitors. Your question would be greatly improved if you could indicate which you think to be correct, and why, so that answerers understand why you have doubts. I strongly encourage you to take the site [tour] and review the [help] for additional guidance.

Answer (score 0):

The title "S and es" implies that you're treating "show" and "acts" as nouns. These words, however, are capable of being used both as a *noun* and as a *verb*, and in your quote the two words are being used as verbs. You can see the question below (actually very recent!) on another example of this:

[Correct word order and subject-verb agreement: "..his associate volunteers..."](https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/136623/correct-word-order-and-subject-verb-agreement-his-associate-volunteers)

And yes, these verbs are conjugated correctly. "Show" is third-person plural, which works with "proposed technique and existing technique" as the subject. Meanwhile, "acts" is third-person singular, which works with "proposed technique" as the subject.

(By the way, rewriting "proposed technique and existing technique" to "proposed and existing techniques" makes the tense a lot clearer.)

Comment: Actually, "show" is related to "results", if you look more carefully. Additionally, the sentence is quite awkward, from my point of view: "results ... are compared which show ..."